# Why does Windows Media Player Library give different file duration on different computers?

Tags: vb.net, wmplib

I have an app in vb.net that plays mp3 files using the WMPlib.  On my system the file duration reads correctly.  10 minutes and some odd seconds.  On a clients system it reads as 5 minutes and some odd seconds.

When I remote into the clients system I can open the file in Windows Media player, play it and it keeps playing past the 5:xx marker.  The marker stops moving, seconds stop changing, it keeps playing.  If I open the same exact file on my system it reads the correct 10:xx.  Really odd!

What's going on here?  What do I need to do to the clients system in order to get the WMPlib reading the correct audio file duration?

I know this has something to do with \system32\WMP.dll just not sure what.  The dll file size matches on the two systems.  We are both running windows 8.1.

What are my options?

Comment: I've seen this happen to media in cases where file header info (or other metadata) is encoded incorrectly. Did you make this mp3 file yourself? Perhaps try encoding it with a different program.

Comment: The original file is coming from a service that records phone calls.  The files in question start with the .WAV extension, and windows media player states that the file format doesn't match that extension.  I use sox.exe and ffmpeg.exe to convert the file depending on the extension. We have audio files coming from many different providers and have no control over the original format.  I have googled the snot out of these issues and have determined the best option is to correct the clients system as it isn't the file conversion tools fault, it is the audio file provider giving a difficult file.